# Is Transposition Cipher perfectly secure?How to prove it?

Tags: encryption

Is Transposition Cipher perfectly secure?How to prove it?
I can't figure it out by comparing `|M|`and `|K|`

Comment: Think about what an attacker can determine from a short (say less than 10 character) message, even if the exact transposition used is unknown.

Comment: Consider if you see the ciphertext of 'AAAAA'; what can you deduce about the plaintext?

Comment: @EugeneStyer Other than that the message / plaintext is short, that's considered out of scope for these kind of theoretical questions about crypto (very much not in practical cryptography, but that's not what this is about).